# How to run vendor provided script from playbook to enable csh environment variables

Tags: ansible

I need to execute a vendor provided csh script to create a veritable plethora of environment variables in order to run application from playbook.

I have built an ad-hoc script that uses screen to inject the commands I need to run inside of a csh session.  This succesfully allows me to run the application; but again, from an ad-hoc script and not a playbook.

```
### start the fsc
# launch a screen session with csh
ansible 10.1.1.103 -m shell -a "su - testdev -c 'screen -dmS testdev_fsc csh'" -b
# run vendor provided env variables script
ansible 10.1.1.103 -m shell -a "su - testdev -c 'screen -S testdev_fsc -X stuff '/export/home/testdev/tcdata/tc_cshvars^M''" -b
# execute the application
ansible 10.1.1.103 -m shell -a "su - testdev -c 'screen -S testdev_fsc -X stuff '/export/home/testdev/ccbin/fsc.sh^M''" -b
```

In the end, I'd like to be able to create a playbook snippet that allows the above to run/execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to become user `testdev` and run two commands in a row in the same csh session. The following fictive playbook should do the job.

```
---
# Playbook example
- name: Play to run my script
  hosts: my_inventory_group
  remote_user: my_remote_connection_user

  tasks
    - name: run my script
      become: true
      become_user: testdev
      shell: |-
        ./tcdata/tc_cshvars
        ./ccbin/fsc.sh
      args:
        chdir: /export/home/testdev/
        executable: /bin/csh
```

`|-` is the yaml litteral block marker with trailing space control. All the following block is interpreted as a string with new lines preserved. Passed to the shell module, each line will be executed (as if entered in your own shell). Double check the path for your csh executable. You must provide an absolute path.

If you have several tasks in your playbook and need to run all or them as `testdev`, you can move `become` and `become_user` to play level rather that task level.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'll be able to try this out tomorrow.  Sadly, I'm a very new account and I can't upvote you.  But I appreciate you taking time to work through this and post up this answer.  Again, thank you kind person!  (Also, are you on the phone while you are belaying someone?  Heh, that, I can't endorse. :P . Get outside and sew up some trad brother! -Long time multi-pitch / big wall climber. :) . Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it fixes your issue. It will tell others there is an accepted solution.

Comment: I will.  I'm in the process of setting up the playbook right now.  I shall report back asap. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... 
https://gist.github.com/Sicnus/3618d7e76b1f31e3752af4f45c5e88f8

Comment: Your are not respecting playbook syntax. Please read [working with playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html). I edited my answer to provide a full playbook example.